# Transfer logs from Android to App Center or Application Insights

Tags: java, android, react-native, azure-application-insights, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using App Center Android SDK v4.4.5 in custom native Android code within a React Native application. I've integrated it successfully which I can observe from logcat. Also, I'm able to see the device/session data and track events in App Center.

My main use case is, apart from tracking errors, to transfer logs from `android.util.logger`. Currently, I can't find a solution for this with App Center.

As a side note, in the React Native layer I've intergrated the Application Insights Web SDK together with React Native plugin. An additional transport of my logger makes use of [TrackTrace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-custom-events-metrics#tracktrace) to transfer the logs. In my Node.js backend logs from Bunyan even are [collected automatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/nodejs#automatic-third-party-instrumentation) by Application Insights by means of a monkey patch applied to Bunyan at runtime.

I'm searching for a similar solution for my Android Logs. Since these logs from my point of view aren't auto-collected, I'd by happy if there was something like `TrackTrace()` which I can implement in a custom logger class. However, it appears that I can only track events.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this? I am looking for the same. Thanks,

Comment: Sadly I wasn't. I've contacted the App Center support because I couldn't believe that a application monitoring tool like this one doesn't support log transfer but read the response yourself:

"It seems that you would like to transfer the logs of debugging applications to App Center. App Center doesn’t have a built-in way to achieve it. For any error/crash happened during running RN apps, App Center uses Crash reporting service to trace crashes and below methods to track errors." Then they referred to some links in the documentation we already know of.

Comment: Oh! Bummer! Thanks so much though.